# How to update particular attribute of entity on google datatstore?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client, datastore

I am integrating google datastore api in php. I am trying to update the entity on google datastore.

```
            $property_map [ 'full_name' ]        = set_string_value( isset($data [ 'full_name' ] ) ? $data [ 'full_name' ] : $data [ 'name' ] ); 
            $property_map [ 'email' ]            = set_string_value( $data [ 'email' ] );
            $property_map [ 'password' ]         = set_string_value( isset($data [ 'password' ] ) ? md5($data [ 'password' ]) : md5(rand()), true );
            $property_map [ 'country' ]          = set_string_value( isset($data [ 'country' ] ) ? $data [ 'country' ] : 'null' ); 
            $property_map [ 'timezone' ]         = set_string_value( isset($data [ 'timezone' ] ) ? $data [ 'timezone' ] : 'America/Chicago' );  
            $property_map [ 'type' ]             = set_string_value( 'free' );
```

I have to provide all the attributes even when I try to update its only one field otherwise all the data is lost. Also if I try to create a sub entity lets say `logs`  I am unable to retain its old entities when update it with a new one. Can anybody please help?

Hi @Frank Yes I've got the entity by key using following code.

```
/*
 *Function to lookup an entity.
 */
function lookup_request($entity_kind,$entity_id){
  $instance = & get_instance();
  $service  = set_google_datastore();
  $req      = get_entity($entity_kind,$entity_id);
  return $service->projects->lookup($instance->config->item('google_project_id'),$req,[]);
}

/*
 *Function to set datatsore instance.
 */
function set_google_datastore(){
  return new Google_Service_Datastore(google_set_client());

}
/*
 *Function to set mutation to get entity.
 */
function get_entity($entity_kind,$entity_id){
  $path = new Google_Service_Datastore_PathElement();
  $path->setKind($entity_kind);
  $path->setId($entity_id);

  $key = new Google_Service_Datastore_Key();
  $key->setPath([$path]);

  $req = new Google_Service_Datastore_LookupRequest();
  $req->setKeys($key);
  return $req;
}
```

Using above code Im able to get the entity. Now what should I do to update it? I am updating it using `setUpdate`. What am I missing Can you please explain?

Comment: When saving an entity in the GAE datastore the entire entity is serialized and (re)written. If you want to update just a subset of its properties you have to first read the entity, then modify the desired properties and save the entity.

Comment: Have you checked out the PHP GDS library? It makes a lot of this stuff straight forward (IMHO)

Comment: https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

Comment: No I didnt try this library but yes I got succeed in doing so by first fetching the entity by key and then updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getting the entity by key before updating it? Then you should be able to modify it without losing properties.

> Also if I try to create a sub entity lets say logs I am unable to retain its old entities when update it with a new one.

Lets call your parent entity `User` and the sub entity `Log`. Have you tried having more than one Log entity per user, perhaps keyed by the creation time (with the User key being the parent, of course)? Effectively you would be adding not updating Log entities for a given user for each event.

Comment: Hi Frank. I've updated the question please check now.